# how can i implement a filter view like this?

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, searchview

[image]

I thought that it's possibile within a fragment, but I'm young android developer and I will know which is the best way to implement it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yup, that's an AlertDialog. However, unless you have an actual problem with implementation, your question is quite broad as we aren't going to create one for you.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of Android material dialog with a custom view should give you a solution

Many libraries exist in gitub. Its just a mater of searching

Answer (score 0):

In Android you do it with an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

You'll want to implement one with a custom layout matching your picture.

An excerpt from the guide:

> If you want a custom layout in a dialog, create a layout and add it to an AlertDialog by calling setView() on your AlertDialog.Builder object.